# Does the Higgs boson contribute to the Casimir effect?

Tags: higgs, casimir-effect

I read that all bosons contribute to the casimir effect with an attractive force.

http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Quantum/casimir.html

Does the Higgs boson contribute to the Casimir effect? Could it be the missing 5%?

Comment: Due to experimental error it's not clear it actually disagrees at all.

Comment: How much force would virtual Higgs bosons exert in theory? Can it be worked out now that we know it's mass?

Answer (score 3):

No, Higgs particles do not contribute to Casimir forces.

[Casimir effect](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Quantum/casimir.html) happens because [virtual particles](http://io9.com/5731463/are-virtual-particles-for-real) are excluded from the gap between two solids **when the separation distance is smaller than the particle wavelength** (multiplied by smallish integers). Its force is barely measurable when objects are within about a micron ($10^{-6}$ m) of each other, and becomes stronger by an inverse-**quartic** function (distance to the 4th power).

The atoms composing a solid object are typically about 1 angstrom ($10^{-10}$ m) apart; atoms themselves are also measured on angstrom scale. Therefore, you can only consider objects to be "separate" from each other at distances of at least nanometer ($10^{-9}$ m) scale. Closer than that, the objects are "touching" and Casimir no longer applies.

A [particle's wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_wavelength) is an inverse function of its mass/energy. A Higgs particle has very high energy (125 GeV) and consequently a very tiny wavelength: $10^{-17}$ meters, smaller than the [radius of a proton](http://scale2.s3.amazonaws.com/scale2.swf). This is vastly below separation distance, therefore Higgs particles cannot contribute to Casimir effect.

Comment: I wonder if its possible to revive the idea by considering non atomic matter (ex: large rectangular plates of pure neutrons under immense pressure and low temperature). You could probably get such matter close enough to see a strong-force casimir effect. But a higgs casimir effect would remain out of reach even then

Comment: for the record i don't understand the math behind the strong force, so i dont know if virtual vacuum gluons and gluon exclusion is a meaningful concept the way it is for virtual photons